# Use of template while making doubly linked list queue?

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, queue

so I am trying to make the queue with the linked list

which uses template in c++ to make any kind of data type queue.

However, it gives me a such error when I am trying to make template with "ListNode" class and its friend class "List":

**Error C2955   'ListNode': use of class template requires template argument**

this error is at line 33 where I declare head listnode and tail list node in List class

```
ListNode* list_head;
ListNode* list_tail;
```

How can I find solution to unite these two classes into template? please help.

below is my code sample:

```
template <typename T>
class ListNode
{
private: 
    T data;
    int priority;
    ListNode* prev;
    ListNode* next;

public:
    ListNode() { prev = next = NULL; }
    ListNode(T d, int pr, ListNode* p, ListNode* n) { data = d; priority = pr; prev = p; next = n; }

    template <typename T>
    friend class List;
};

template <typename T>
class List
{
private:
    ListNode* list_head;
    ListNode* list_tail;

public:
    List() { list_head = list_tail = NULL; }
    ~List() { clear(); }

    bool isEmpty() { return list_head == NULL; }
    bool contains(T value);

    void addToQueList(T value, int priority);

    T head() { return list_head->data; }
    T tail() { return list_tail->data; }

    T removeHead();
    T removeTail();
    void clear();
};

template <typename T>
bool List<T>::contains(T value)
{
    ListNode *temp = list_head;
    while (temp != NULL && temp->data != value)
        temp = temp->next;

    return temp != NULL;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried getting the linked list working without templates?  I recommend getting this to work without templates.  Converting working code to using templates is simple.

Comment: I recommend looking at other examples, by searching the internet for "StackOverflow templat linked list"

Comment: As `ListNode` is a template class you need to provide a template parameter. I guess the template parameter of the list should also be the one for the nodes, so you need to declare `list_head` and `list_tail` as `ListNode<T>*` inside your list class

Comment: And also in your contains function: `ListNode<T>* temp = list_head`

Comment: @MikevanDyke Or just write `auto temp = list_head;` and be done with it.

Comment: Thank you! solved the problems with the method!